# Executing command in docker container after compose up

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm trying to automate the execution of some command(s) in a docker container after compose up. My first idea was to use a gradle `DockerExecContainer` task (provided by docker plugin) and retrieve the target container id from the `dockerCompose` extension (provided by  docker compose plugin).

I thought something like this would work:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose' version '0.12.1'
    id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '6.4.0'
}

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerExecContainer

task setupPhabricator(type: DockerExecContainer) {
    containerId.set(dockerCompose.servicesInfos.phabricator.firstContainer.containerId)
    commands.add(['echo', '$PHABRICATOR_HOST'] as String[]) 
}

dockerCompose {
    isRequiredBy(setupPhabricator)
}
```

This fails because `dockerCompose.servicesInfos.phabricator` is `null`. This makes sense because at configuration time the container is not up yet.

I figured I should set the container ID during the execution phase:

```
task setupPhabricator(type: DockerExecContainer) {
    commands.add(['echo', '$PHABRICATOR_HOST'] as String[])
    doFirst {
        containerId.set(dockerCompose.servicesInfos.phabricator.firstContainer.containerId)
    }
}
```

But this fails with:

> `No value has been specified for property 'containerId'`

I assume I'm missing something fundamental here so any idea is welcome.

Comment: I am not familiar with gradle but for the process you want to implement I would suggest asking docker directly instead of docker-compose. You can run `docker container ls --filter name=<service_name> --format "{{.ID}}"` (replacing service_name with your service). This command should return the ID of the container(s) you are looking for.

Comment: Scripting `docker exec` isn't usually a recommended approach.  (It requires running an orchestrator around your orchestrator, and in cluster environments where containers can be restarted outside your control, you'll potentially miss the manual setup step.)  Can you use something like an entrypoint wrapper script for the container to set itself up?

Comment: I had a similar issue. What I did was run `docker-compose up --scale <service_to_automate>=0 -d`, and then `docker-compose run --rm <service_to_automate> <script>`.